# error_get_last() возвращает null

Tags: php

например, делаю так:

```
$var = ss; //неопределённая константа, например
file_put_contents('1.log', var_export(error_get_last(), true));
```

В итоге получаю null

Пример реального кода:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
  //...
}

function fatal_error_handler()
{
    chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dsm2.7f2_local/dsm2');
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error && $error['type'] == E_ERROR) {
        sendErrorMessage('troopermanowar@gmail.com', 'Error', 'Fatal error!');
        error_handler($error['type'], $error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
    }
}

function sendErrorMessage($email, $subject, $msg)
{
   //...
}

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
set_error_handler("error_handler");
register_shutdown_function('fatal_error_handler');
```

Comment: Значит ошибок не было, очевидно же. Неопределённая константа - это нотайс, преобразуется в строку. Нотайсы отлавливаются по другому.

Comment: вот же ошибка в первой строчке - несуществующая константа

Comment: ок, поменяем на `$var[];`, это уже Fatal error

Comment: ок, а Fatal error ловится вообще по другому - как-то так `register_shutdown_function(function(){ if (!($error = error_get_last())){ return;} file_put_contents('1.log', var_export($error, true));});` . Только `register_shutdown_function` - должен быть в начале програмы. Фаталы после такого объявления будут попадать в коллбек.

Comment: изначально я так и делал, но так как не срабатывало решил проверить что вообще возвращает эта функция.

Answer (score 1):

Есть в общем перехват любых ошибок кроме фаталов с помощью `set_error_handler` . Фатал можно перехватить с помощью `register_shutdown_function` . Есть ещё `set_exception_handler` - для особого типа ошибок "неперехваченные исключения".  Перехватчики надо определить в начале программы - например с конструированием объекта вроде Logger.

Ну и вручную исключение перехватывается с помощью `try{..}catch(Exception $e){/*перехват тут*/}` - если не перехватывать, то перехватит `set_error_handler` или `set_exception_handler` , но надо помнить - что фаталы, нотайсы, стрикты (типы ошибок) - к исключениям не относятся, иногда и варнинги не относятся.

Вот и вся обработка ошибок в PHP - если наладить запись в лог всех ошибок и нотайсов: помогает хорошо, позволяет продуцировать правильно работающий код.

Comment: через set_error_handler  всё работает, но надо и фаталы тоже заносить в лог, а вот с этим проблема возникла

Comment: @Jonny Manowar - для этого `register_shutdown_function` работает железно. Только определить его надо до фатала - конечно)

Comment: определяю я её конечно же в начале файла index.php

Comment: @Jonny Manowar Значит перехват происходит - но ошибка на этапе записи. В твоём коде - вставь после `if ($error && $error['type'] == E_ERROR)` строки `var_dump(123);die();` - ты увидишь 123, а это значит что перехват произошёл. И `chdir` - 100 лет уже такого не видел, пиши по абсолютному пути - так правильнее. То есть не забуть в index.php объявить путь сайта `define('PATH', __DIR__)` .

Comment: var_dump не вывел ничего

Comment: @Jonny Manowar возможно у тебя не фатал. Точно помню, что фатал генерирует вызов несуществующей ф-ии: попробуй это. Или попробуй var_dump перед if-ом, этож основа отладки)

Comment: так и есть. при несуществующей функции перехватывает. но не выводит. и как другие подобные ошибки ловить?

Comment: @Jonny Manowar он и не должен выводить. У тебя же стоит `ini_set('display_errors', 'off')`. Подобные ошибки то есть фаталы ты и перехватываешь с помощью `register_shutdown_function`  - в error_get_last() у тебя есть и линия и сообщение ошибки. Для остальных ошибок ещё можно получить `$error->getTraceAsString();` - оч. важная инфа, для фатала нельзя без расширения xdebug .

Comment: я о том и говорю, что не должен но некоторые всё же выводит